# Error when compiling simple LLVM example with Mingw

Tags: windows, compilation, mingw, llvm

I'm trying to learn about `LLVM API` working on Windows, I have installed `LLVM 3.6` (`llvm tools`, `clang`, etc) successfully, have `Mingw` and I'm trying to compile [this example](https://gist.github.com/alloy/d86b007b1b14607a112f).

both commmands work on my environment:

```
clang -c -emit-llvm test.c -o test.ll
llc -march=cpp test.ll -o test.cpp
```

but when trying to compile this new `test.cpp` file I got:

```
C:\Users\Alex\Desktop>clang test.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs core` -o test
clang.exe: error: unsupported option '--cxxflags'
clang.exe: error: unsupported option '--ldflags'
clang.exe: error: unsupported option '--libs'
clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '`llvm-config'
clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'core`'
```

Any idea? I'm very newbie using `LLVM`.

Comment: This isn't a MinGW issue. Nor is it an LLVM issue. It appears to be a basic misuse of the Windows command line interpreter, `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using Windows' `cmd.exe` as your shell, (i.e. command interpreter), but you are attempting to invoke the `clang` command using a Unix Bourne shell syntax, (the back-tick quoted `llvm-config` command substitution), which `cmd.exe` simply doesn't understand.

If you want to use this command syntax, then you'd better find a more capable shell than `cmd.exe`; perhaps try MSYS or cygwin.

Comment: It looks like I'm on the right way but now I'm receiving these messages (Cygwin):

<code>
Alex@Home-PC /cygdrive/c/users/Alex/desktop
$ clang test.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs core` -o test
clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'Files'
clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '(x86)\LLVM/include'
clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'Files'
clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '(x86)\LLVM/lib'
</code>

it looks like problems with spaces(?), I have installed LLVM in %ProgramFiles% -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM"

Comment: @Jac0b, I can't help with cygwin usage issues, because I don't use it.  However, spaces in path names, (and maybe also parentheses), are _always_ going to be troublesome. Microsoft did their users a gross disservice, when they introduced this convention; what would have been so wrong with `c:\ProgramFilesX86`, which is not only easier for any program to parse, but to my (human) eye at least, scans more readily as a single entity.